# Change second dropdown dinamically based after value in first one

Tags: flutter

I have 2 dropdown and one dropdown value depends on the first one:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  EventDao dao;
  Home(this.dao,{Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height= MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return  Scaffold(
      body: Placeholder()
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child:Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context)
          {
            return showOverlay(widget.dao);
          });
        },),
    );
  }



  Widget showOverlay(EventDao dao){
    String? selectedTypeItem="Seleziona una tipologia";
    String? selectedCatItem="Seleziona una categoria"; 
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    var isDropDownCatVisible=true;
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                 DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                      onSaved: (value)=>event.eventType=value!,
                      value: selectedTypeItem,
                      items: EventType.eventType.map((item)=>
                          DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: item, child: Text(item))).toList(),
                      onChanged: (item)=>setState((){
                          selectedTypeItem =item;
                          if(selectedTypeItem=="Uscita"){
                          isDropDownCatVisible=true;
                          print(isDropDownCatVisible);}
                          else if (selectedTypeItem=="Entrata"){
                            isDropDownCatVisible=false;

                          }

                      })
                  ),
                ),

             DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                      onSaved: (value)=>event.eventCat=value!,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText:'Categoria Evento'
                      ),
                      value: selectedCatItem,
                      items: getItems(isDropDownCatVisible)?.map((item)=>
                    DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: item, child: Text(item))).toList(),
                      onChanged: (item)=>setState(() =>
                      selectedCatItem =item)
                  ),
                ),
               
           ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<String>? getItems(bool isDropDownCatVisible) {
    if(isDropDownCatVisible) {
      return LIST1;

    }
    return LIST2;
  }
```

I change the isDropDownCatVisible in setState of 1st dropdown, so i expect that flutter recharge all the widget tree thus changing also the list in the second drop down.

EventCategory.eventInCat this contains the 1st list of values

EventCategory.eventInCat; this contains the second list of values

Comment: can you make it minimal by providing all data,More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: LIST 1 is the first list of string, whille LIST 2 is the second one